# How can I run speech to text and save the result in a variable?

Tags: shell, assignment, speech-recognition

I would like to speak into my computer's microphone, have what I say converted to text and then have that available as a shell variable.

Is this possible? I thought I might do it using Google's speech input feature:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? Can you give us an example? Also, in your screenshot, the text in the "search bar" is `https://www.google.com`. Do you mean the text in Google's search field? If so, would you want it for all search fields? Only Google's? Please[edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Yes I just typed in the bar in search field. Did Not enter button. Actual requirements is I want to say something in voice to google chrome using microphone. Then through the linux i want to access the word from google chrome.

Comment: OK. But to do what? Why do you need to go through chrome first? I doubt it will be possible without actually hitting enter and running the search. If what you want is to convert speech to text and save as a variable, please [edit] your question and make that clear. Don't add another comment, *[edit]*. Comments are easy to miss and hard to read.

Comment: @terdon changed the title. Do  you answer please.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using [nerd-dictation](https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation):

```bash
SPEECH="$(nerd-dictation begin --timeout=1.0 --output=STDOUT)"
```